# Duda con una prueba de escritorio de un programa Java

Tags: java, array, bucles

tengo la siguiente duda de mi clase de Fundamentos de programación, el profesor nos facilita el siguiente codigo:

```
import java.util.Arrays; 

public class blablabla {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] v1 = new int[] {9,6,2,1,4,0};
    int j;

    for (int i=1; i<v1.length; i++){

        int temp=v1[i];
        j=i-1;
        while (j>=0 && v1[j] > temp){
            v1[j+1] = v1[j];
            j--;
//                System.out.println("I es:" + i);
//                System.out.println("J es:" + j);
//                System.out.println("Temp es:" + temp);
        }
        v1[j+1]=temp;
//            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v1));
    }

}
}
```

A este codigo había que hacerle una prueba de escritorio (a papel y lapiz) para organizar el array de menor a mayor, entonces mi duda es, ¿por qué el programa empieza con j=-1 cuando i=1 y logra organizar el array correctamente? Ya que el profesor cuando hace la prueba en una hoja de escritorio dice que J=0 cuando i=1 y al seguir el programa linea a linea organiza el array correctamente.

Comment: El programa imprime lo siguiente: I es:1
J es:-1
Temp es:6
[6, 9, 2, 1, 4, 0]
I es:2
J es:0
Temp es:2
I es:2
J es:-1
Temp es:2
[2, 6, 9, 1, 4, 0]
I es:3
J es:1
Temp es:1
I es:3
J es:0
Temp es:1
I es:3
J es:-1
Temp es:1
[1, 2, 6, 9, 4, 0]
I es:4
J es:2
Temp es:4
I es:4
J es:1
Temp es:4
[1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 0]
I es:5
J es:3
Temp es:0
I es:5
J es:2
Temp es:0
I es:5
J es:1
Temp es:0
I es:5
J es:0
Temp es:0
I es:5
J es:-1
Temp es:0
[0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 9]

Comment: fíjate que j no es j=-1 sino j=i-1. Al empezar el bucle, i = 1 con lo cual si j= i-1, j = 0.

Comment: J solo vale -1 cuando sale del bucle, simplemente porque esa es la condición para salir del bucle, es decir que se repiten las acciones correctas a realizar siempre que J >= 0 y van reduciendiendo J hasta que "se sale" de la zona de acción. Ademas, de ese detalle, hay otro que crea tu confusión, y es simplemente que imprimes los valores despues de decrementar J, con esto quiero decir que si imprimes los valores despues de realizar la operacion sobre el array y antes de decrementar la J obtndrás una impresión correcta de las acciones.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación.

Comment: Mateo, si entendiste la explicación deberías postear la respuesta y marcarla como válida para cerrar la pregunta, o también @JuanJoseBurgosVeiga deberías poner esa explicación como respuesta.

Comment: Gracias @Leandro, ahora mismo preparo una respuesta detallada de mi comentario.

Answer (score 1):

dado que mi explicación en el comentario anterior se ha considerado más bien una respuesta, detallo la misma a continuación.

El valor **J** solo vale -1 en el último paso del bucle antes de salir del mismo porque esa es la condición para salir del bucle, es decir que se repiten las acciones correctas a realizar siempre que **J >= 0** y aplican el decremento de **J** hasta que "se sale" de la zona de acción.

Además, de ese detalle, hay otro puede "confundir" cuando se aprende. En este caso es el hecho que se "imprime" los valores en cada ciclo después de decrementar **J** (que prepara el siguiente paso del bucle). Con esto quiero decir que si imprimes los valores después de realizar la operacion sobre el array y antes de decrementar la **J** obtndrás una impresión correcta de las acciones.

PS: Gracias de nuevo a @Leandro.